# Get the file name after click open button in file browse dialog box using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Basically I am new in web development and I'm facing a problem related to open `file dialog box` using `JavaScript` or `jQuery` my problem is that how can I open a `file browser dialog box` and after clicking `open` button in the `file dialog box` get the file `path` or `name` in `alert()` method.

**I am using below code for show dialog box in JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function performClick(node) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);
        var pathnew = document.getElementById('theFile').value;

    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('theFile'));">Open file dialog</a>
<input type="file" id="theFile" />
```

above code shows perfectly file browse dialog box but this alert box show when I click on 
`Open file dialog` but I need after clicking Open button which is under the File browse dialog box. 
Please Help me!

Any help will be appropriated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form>
    <input type="file">
</form>
<script>
  $(":file").change(function(){
    alert($(":file").val());
  });
</script>
```

put it on jsfiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ytkn/

Comment: @JayShukla it gives path as `c:\fakepath\<filename>`. it will not give full absolute file path. I am also trying for that but not getting.

Comment: you need to change your browser settings. This is an added security feature in html5 
http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-get-rid-of-cfakepath-in-ie-when-uploading-a-file-to-the-website-fix/

Comment: My problem is when i run this code in IE11 it doesn't fire the alert!?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `value` of the `<input type="file" />`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is right...Should produce a "Browse" button:

```
<input id="file_field" type="file"></input>

<button type="button" onclick="DisplayFilePath();">Display file path</button>

<script>
function DisplayFilePath(){
    alert($("#file_field").val())
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<SCRIPT>
    function reverseData(val)       {var d="";var temp="";for (var x=val.length;x>0;x--) {d+=val.substring(x,eval(x-1));}return d;}
    function getFilename(val)       {val=escape(val);var reversedsrc=reverseData(val);var nameEnd=reversedsrc.indexOf('C5%');var name=reversedsrc.substring(0,nameEnd);name=reverseData(name);name=unescape(name);return name;}
    var daname='val';
    document.write('<INPUT TYPE="file" ID="val"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Get File Name" ONCLICK="alert(getFilename(window.document.getElementById(daname).value))">');
</SCRIPT>
```

put it into html file and test

Comment: Sir thanx for your reply but I need show alert box after clicking `Open` button which is appear in `dialog box`.